# Python: List inside a Dict?

Tags: python

From this example, how do I get the **IP address** from the response?

```
import requests

URL = "https://security.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=test.com"

session = requests.session()
r = session.get(URL, headers={"Accept": "application/dns-json"})
r = r.json()

print("Type:", type(r))
print("Len:", len(r))
print("Content:", r)

IP = r['Answer'][-1]
print("IP:", IP)
```

Output:

```
Type: <class 'dict'>
Len: 8
Content: {'Status': 0, 'TC': False, 'RD': True, 'RA': True, 'AD': False, 'CD': False, 'Question': [{'name': 'test.com', 'type': 1}], 'Answer': [{'name': 'test.com', 'type': 1, 'TTL': 3261, 'data': '69.172.200.235'}]}
IP: {'name': 'test.com', 'type': 1, 'TTL': 3261, 'data': '69.172.200.235'}
```

Comment: So could you just use `IP['data']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?:

```
IP = r['Answer'][-1]['data']
print("IP:", IP)
```

Output:

```
IP: 69.172.200.235
```

Comment: Glad it works @Andre! Also, you could consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

The reply is:

```
r['Answer'][0]['data']
```

But I would like to give you a tip on how you could find this.

I like to use the code module to run an interactive console inside my script:

```
import requests
import code

URL = "https://security.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=test.com"

session = requests.session()
r = session.get(URL, headers={"Accept": "application/dns-json"})
r = r.json()

print("Type:", type(r))
print("Len:", len(r))
print("Content:", r)

code.interact(banner="after get request", locals=locals()) #interactive console is created here

IP = r['Answer'][-1]
print("IP:", IP)
```

From there, you can play with local variables and test until you find what you need.

I hope that will helps.